# How can I set polygon width in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here i am try to set polygon outline width but it give me error.

Please flow below code.

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw

img = Image.new("RGB", (1024, 1024), "white")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.polygon((924, 266, 245, 777, 241, 782, 306, 100, 924, 266), fill="white", outline="black")
```

[image]

```
img_new_name="C:/example/Garpani_corrected.png"

img.save(img_new_name, quality=90)
```

Comment: You had tags for ArcGIS and QGIS but make no mention of using either in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The draw.polygon does not accept "width" parameter however, draw.line does. You can create the desired output using draw.line function:

```
draw.line((924, 266, 245, 777, 241, 782, 306, 100, 924, 266), fill="black", width=5)
```

[image]